# jQuery doesn't handle event.target properly. Why?

Tags: jquery

I have this simple piece of jQuery code:

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e){
   if (e.target.tagName == 'INPUT'){
      e.preventDefault();
      e.target.val('text');
   }
});
```

And of course my HTML input element:

```
<input />
```

When I type anything into this input, I get the following error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: e.target.val is not a function.

Am I missing something here?

EDIT:

**However**, this works as expected (just tested it to make sure I'm targeting the correct element):

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e){
   if (e.target.tagName == 'INPUT'){
      e.preventDefault();
      e.target.remove();
   }
});
```

Comment: Typo: it should be `e.target.value = 'text';` or `$(e.target).val ('text');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`e.target.val` is not a function, you are confusing it with the jQuery val function `$(e.target).val('text');`

If you want to you could use `e.target.value = 'text';` as well.

Comment: Wow OK, thanks. I guess it confused me that ``e.target.remove();`` did work.

Comment: `remove()` is a function of the native DOM nodes, as well as a jQuery method.